# Добавление пользователя в друзья

Tags: php, база-данных, mysql

Как сделать, чтобы один пользователь мог добавить другого в друзья?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Делаем таблицу `friend_requests {id,r_from,r_to,r_accepted}`

При клике на "добавить" создаем в ней запись (r_accepted = 0), т.е. делаем заявку на добавление.

Она высвечивается у второго ("`SELECT * FROM friend_requests WHERE r_to=$myID AND r_accepted=0;`"), если он ее принимает - ставим r_accepted = 1;

Дальше посмотреть всех друзей можно так: "`SELECT * FROM friend_requests WHERE (r_from=$myID OR r_to=$myID) AND r_accepted=1;`"

Comment: Мне кажется не стоит хранить записи людей, которые отказались дружить с пользователем, т.к. наверно таблица с друзьями и так будет очень большой. Например, можно в какою-нить другую таблицу скинуть информацию об их отказе, т.о. время выборки при просмотре списка друзей будет ниже :)

Comment: Ну их можно вообще не хранить) Вконтакт вообще удаляет, одноглазники и моймир вроде уведомления об отказе шлют. Просто решил не освещать, там сами решат, что с отказами делать.